# Can I add arguments to a program in windows without using a shortcut?

Tags: windows, shortcuts, command-line-arguments

Is it possible to add arguments to a file without creating a shortcut to it in windows? Specifically windows XP, Vista, and 7? If so, how would you do it?

I'm not talking about using a batch file, or something like that. I mean I have an executable jar, and I'd like it to pass the Swing application some arguments but it seems like my users would have to create a shortcut to do that. I would like to avoid this if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the options/parameters are hard-coded, you'd need *some* way to pass them on to the application during start-up. If you have the Java source you can obviously edit it as needed, but if you simply have an executable JAR (executable provided JRE is installed, of course), then there's no possible way I can think of to embed arguments in the file itself.

Comment: Sadface :( Thanks for the answer though.